# Memory full on windows CE 6.0 program

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I currently have a program that was written in VS 2010 vb.net and compact framework 3.5 and is running on windows CE 6.0(COMTECH CUWIN 5000). This hardware uses an SDK as well

The program reads from Comm ports on a timer, does calculations, displays on the CE screen then sends a string over a Comm port to another computer.

My program is crashing due to memory full every 8-10 hours or so and I cannot figure out why.

I have tried adding a garbage collector at the end of one of my timer ticks but that has not helped only slowed the problem.

A copy of my solution can be found here if you would like to take a look and figure it out.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bLK_ChVJk-OUJHeXk0cWJqdU0/view?usp=sharing

This solution was translated from VB6. Also I an new to programming so I have a beginners knowledge base to work from.

Thanks in advance
John

Comment: You possibly hit a limit for ListBox1 or ListBox2. You should consider a Items.Clear after some time or so. You can not add unlimitted number of items to a listbox.

Comment: I agree with that but the window with those list boxes is only opened during diagnostics. The frmMain is the only for running constantly.

Comment: Although it is not shown, the frmDiagnostics listbox is filled with every timer1 tick. Why do you access the frmDiagnostics elements when the form is not shown?

Comment: well spotted, I am going to re-code that part.